# can't create .txt with for

Tags: java, syntax-error

I want to create 10 txt files with for in Eclipse but
why when i'm doing this i get error?

```
for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) 
File i = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FOLDER- OS test\\primer" + i + ".txt");
```

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
     Assignment
    - File cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - i cannot be resolved to a variable
    - i cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: Eclipse has a very good quicktip/helping system. Also, *always* wrap for-loops with brackets! And don't reuse variable names.

Comment: Also import classes needed like File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to re-assign to the variable `i`, which has already been defined as an `int`. Just use another variable name for the file, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
   File foo = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FOLDER- OS test\\primer" + i + ".txt");
   foo.createNewFile();
}
```